# How to get rid of `no-unused-expressions` eslint error, for `&&` and `?:` usage?

Tags: javascript, eslintrc

Problem statement:

> this.componentC && this.componentC.render() // by default, this throws **error**, per `no-unused-expressions` eslint rule

Answer (score 1):

`&&` is appropriate when you need to evaluate whether two expressions are truthy. If that isn't the situation - for example, if you need to test for `expression1`'s truthyness before evaluating some other expression (like a function call), then you should use `if` statements. To fix your original code:

```
if (this.componentC) this.componentC.render();
```

Linters warn about unused expressions because they're a code smell and are an indication that you're probably implementing something wrong, like here.

Similarly, with the conditional (ternary) operator, instead, if you have an unused expression:

```
someCondition
? someFn1()
: someFn2();
```

if you're not using the *result* of the expression, you should use `if/else` instead:

```
if (someCondition) someFn1();
else someFn2();
```

One of the main goals of programming should be to write clear, understandable code - don't shirk on code character count just for the heck of it, unless you're [golfing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf).

Answer (score 0):

Below is my recommendation:

Just add the below `overrides` entry to your `.eslintrc.json/js`

```
overrides: [{
        files: ["./src/*.js"],
        rules: {
            "no-unused-expressions": [{
                "allowShortCircuit": true,
                "allowTernary": true
            }]
        },
    }
],
```